# developing on the tizen device

Tags: javascript, html, tizen

This code is a part of my application, doesn't work on the tizen device while it work normally on the tizen simulator ... can anyone have a look and tell me why!! If it's a problem with the balise form or with the dom parser! Can anyone tell me how to solve it?

thx

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
                                           

</head>
<body>
<div id="result">
</div>
<div align="center">
<form  name="myForm">

<button  type="submit">go</button>
</form>  
</div>

<script>
    //var doc;
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.sntri.com.tn/html_ar/result_tarif_horaire_sntri.php', true);
 //xhr.setRequestHeader('Origin', 'www.sntri.com.tn');
 //xhr.setRequestHeader('Allow-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
 xhr.send();
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(4 === xhr.readyState) {
   if(200 === xhr.status) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(xhr.responseText, 'text/html');
    var myForm = document.forms.myForm;
    //console.log(doc);
    var selectDep = doc.getElementsByName('code_arret_dep')[0];
    var selectArr = doc.getElementsByName('code_arret_arr')[0];
    doc.getElementBy
    //console.log(select); 
    myForm.appendChild(selectDep); 
    myForm.appendChild(selectArr);
    //console.log(xhr.responseText);
 
    myForm.onsubmit = function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('POST', 'http://www.sntri.com.tn/html_ar/result_tarif_horaire_sntri.php', true);
     xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
     xhr.send('code_arret_dep='+selectDep.value+'&code_arret_arr='+selectArr.value);
     
     xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(4 === xhr.readyState) {
       if(200 === xhr.status) {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(xhr.responseText, 'text/html');
        var result = document.getElementById('result');
        var tablex = doc.getElementById('tablex');
        //console.log(doc);
        result.appendChild(tablex);
        //console.log(xhr.responseText);
       }
      }
     }
     
     console.log(selectDep.value);
     console.log(selectArr.value);
    }
   }
  }
 };
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tizen + Dom Parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748412/tizen-dom-parser)

Answer (score 0):

Do you add the internet privilege?
You can add the privilege in config.xml.

1. Open the config.xml on Tizen IDE.
2. Select the privileges tap.
3. Click the 'Add' button.
4. Select the http://tizen.org/privilege/internet
5. Run your application.

Comment: yes i have add it but it does not work on the device

Comment: Could you test again with "<access origin="\*" subdomains="\*"></access>"? That also add to config.xml.

Comment: yes yes i have add it ! i don't know why the balise form in the simulator is shown but in the device no :/